# efficient algorithm for grouping of graph nodes in parallel/cluster

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm thinking on the efficient algorithm for joining players into games. Since there will be huge amount of players the algorithm should be asynchronous (i.e. scalable to any number of machines in the cluster).
There are details:
Imagine there is an undirected graph (each node is a player). Each edge between players means that the players can take part in the same game and if there is no edge they can't. I need to implement algorithm that will group the players by following criteria:

- each player has a state: "waiting for game" or "in game". Only waiting players should be grouped into games
- each game has minimal and maximum number of players

My thoughts on the implementation:
The graph will be stored and accessed through NoSQL database (from different machines in the cluster). There is no particular schema yet (any suggestions?). Also locking access to individual player(s) (aka pessimistic lock) is not an option because it's a potential bottleneck of slowing down other processes that will try to access/collect the same player(s).

My question is: has anybody implemented such algorithms? Any suggestions?

PS: I already have raw idea but first want to discuss/check what people suggest.

Thanks!

EDIT1:
In response to Thomas Jungblut:
Using game slots is an interesting idea but (as soon as I understand it correctly) it may not work in some cases. Fox example: Each game should have exactly 3 players. New 6 players (lets call them A B C D E F, see exaple 1) come into the graph/queue one by one in this order: A, B, E, F, C, D.

[example 1](http://s7.postimg.org/xmu3452qz/ex1.png)

As result only one game will be created (A, B, C), plus 2 games with empty slots: (D) and (E, F). But the optimal should be 2 games: (A, C, D) and (B, E, F), right?

Comment: Maybe there is a good implementation based on MapReduce?

Comment: What's your time requirement? If you think MapReduce is an option for you, you'll certainly can wait hours for grouping people into games (which sounds odd to me). I personally would use a messaging queue and put people greedily in games with free slots. You can do this with a simple mysql DB. Also you should define "huge amounts of players" in a more scientific unit.

Comment: Regarding game slots, see my edit above. There are no specific time requirements... It depends on technology Ill use and many other factors. My goal is to implement an algorithm(s) and then analyze its(their) performance, cons and pros. "huge amounts of players" -- lets assume it as a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have not properly thought through the business requirements.

Phrases like "optimal matching" with arbitrary conditions smells NP-complete to me.  You're not going to find an efficient exact solution to one of those with a large data set, merely a reasonable approximation.

And what is the cost of a suboptimal match?  You wind up having to wait slightly longer to find someone play.  Not really a problem.

I would implement something simple like this.  Have a queue of games you are setting up.  Each person who comes in tries to be slotted into the first game, failing that the second, failing that the third, and so on.  If none can be found, you create a new game at the end of the queue.  A game starts when it hits its maximum size, or a fixed amount of time after hitting its minimum.  When a game starts, it is removed from the front of the queue.

With that decided, why you think there will be a million active players?

If it is because you're a startup with big dreams, I would strongly advise you that you need to focus on solving your known problems as efficiently as possible.  In the unlikely event of success (seriously, have you seen the stats?), you can scale later.  And only solving real problems will sharply improve your odds of success all of the way from horrendous to merely poor.  (I don't mean to be discouraging.  But the startup dream really is poor odds of insane returns.  Every action you take should be geared towards improving the odds.)

If you're an established game company that has good reason to believe that you'll hit those figures, read on.

The obvious note that I shouldn't have to mention is that you'll want to implement performance critical bits in a relatively fast language.  If you're writing, for instance, mostly in Python, this would be a good piece to write in Java, Go, or C++.

Next, the first thing that won't scale is player information.  So distribute that.  Doing this will slow your "can player fit in game" check.  So add per game locking, and distribute that calculation asynchronously.  Limit how hard you'll try to get into a game before giving up and creating a new one.

The next bottleneck is the game matching calculation.  So move on to distributing the "new game here" to multiple machines.  Now a player shows up, gets a central list of games to check, starts checking them.  To avoid bottlenecks, players should sort the list of waiting games randomly.

The net bottleneck is asking for that list.  The list is mostly read-only, so you can just use replicated instances of Redis.  Writes (for new games, and marking games started) can go to master, reads can be distributed across as many machines as you need.  Players will hit a random copy of Redis, get a list, sort it randomly.

I would be shocked if you hit this level of scale.  If you exceed it, I'll leave next steps like sharding Redis to you.

Random note.  This is a decent type of interview question.  "Design this simple thing.  Make it scale.  Make it scale more.  Make it scale more."  If you're actually looking for a person who understands distributed performance, that's a good test.  (But only if the interviewer can tell good from bad answers.)

Comment: At first, thanks for the detailed answer. You also confirmed some my guesses. I agree 100% that "perfect" (or NP-complete) algorithm will take much more time (or even impossible) and your solution seems to have the best quality-to-performance value. Regarding players count, yeah, this is very abstract number, and I'm trying to estimate it. So this sounds like "how many players will this algorithm carry being implemented on X technology and running on X hardware".

Comment: "...Next, the first thing that won't scale is player information. So distribute that. Doing this will slow your "can player fit in game" check. So add per game locking, and distribute that calculation asynchronously..." It's not clear. Did you mean calculation of edges between new player and other waiting players? If yes then you are right, in this case I should lock the player when adding edges to it.

Comment: I do mean the calculation of edges between a new player and other waiting players.  So you need to lock the game while doing those lookups.  But do in such a way that you can continue calculating other games at the same time.